# What does "cleanup: fatal: didn't find priority 'LOG_IF00', exiting" mean and how to fix this?

Tags: debian, logging, syslog

"cleanup: fatal: didn't find priority 'LOG_IF00', exiting" - such a message (usually in doubles - twice a time) pops up in my Debian console from time to time. What can that mean and how do I fix this? [Google says](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22fatal%3A+didn%27t+find+priority%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) this is something related to postfix-policyd and syslog.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Install Debian 5.0.5.
2. Install and configure iRedMail 0.6.0 with OpenLDAP.
3. Add unstable and experimental repositories to apt sources list.
4. Upgrade and dist-upgrade until there is nothing more to upgrade.
5. Fix errors in dovecot config (there are some parameters changed in the new version).
6. Then everything runs, but does not work actually an the above message pops up from time to time.

Comment: Could you post the link to your Google search. The only thing I find points to this question.

Comment: Thank you for interest in helping, Dennis. I've updated this in the question now (click on 'Google says' and look at the bottom of the results page).

Comment: Are you using postfix-policyd? If so, what version?

Answer (score 2):

Look at your log_mail variable in the postfix-policyd configuration.  Does go something like this?

```
log_mail=ifoo@syslog...
```

If my guess is right, just change that "ifoo" to "info" and you'll be set.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have a syntax error in your greylist perl script for postfix.  Make sure the syslog line in that script looks like this:

**syslog $syslog_priority, "request age %d", $now - $time_stamp if $verbose;**

You should be able to locate your greylist per script from an entry in /etc/postfix/master.cf file.

Answer (score 0):

The line in question appears to come from an [old version of policyd](http://svn.linuxrulz.org/WebSVN/blame.php?repname=Policyd&path=%2Ftrunk%2Fsyslog.c&rev=0&sc=0):

logmessage("fatal: didn't find priority '%s', exiting\n", token);

IFOO doesn't match any of the known log levels, so it terminates; it probably meant INFO. My suggestion is to install [ack-grep](http://packages.debian.org/ack-grep) and look in `/etc` for a config file containing IFOO. Then you can determine whether it came from Debian directly, iRedMail directly, or was munged in a script. Given the sorry state of the iRedMail installer, I'd probably look there first.

Once you find the file, change it to INFO and you could be fine.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, this is a spacing mistake in two files, not just one (as other threads on the internet have identified, depending on your build):

in both files:

```
/etc/postfix-policyd.conf
/etc/postfix-policyd_sender_throttle.conf
```

edit the line:

```
SYSLOG_FACILITY="LOG_MAIL | LOG_INFO"
```

removing the spaces, so it reads:

```
SYSLOG_FACILITY="LOG_MAIL|LOG_INFO"
```

in both files. then, restart services:

```
/etc/init.d/postfix restart
/etc/init.d/postfix-policyd restart
```

then you can test by running:

```
/usr/lib/postfix-policyd/cleanup -c /etc/postfix-policyd.conf
```

and it should no longer give the error

```
"cleanup: fatal: didn't find priority 'LOG_IFOO', exiting"
```

Hope this helps!

Also as a side-note, this affected me on my Amazon EC2 instance, when I was running Debian 5.0 "Lenny" and started happening after I upgraded it to Debian 6.0.6 "Squeeze". It didn't seem to give me any trouble with functionality, it was just running in log files and showing up in the console every ~10 minutes.